# Length of a string using NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have tries to write a code in NASM to get the length of the given string. But is gives some garbage value as a length. The code is the following one:

```
    section .data
        a db "nitin",10,0
        msg db "length = %d",10,0
    section .text
        global main
        extern printf
    main:
         nop
         xor eax,eax
         mov eax, a
         xor edx,edx
    length:
         mov dl, byte[eax]
         cmp dl,0
         je print
         inc eax
         jmp length

    print:
         pusha
         push eax
         push msg
         call printf
         add esp,8
         popa
    done:
         nop
```

The result is shown:
         Length =132445678

Can you please help me to sort out my mistake?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EAX in your snippet follows the address of the byte, not the index in the string. So instead of length, you're printing out the address of the terminating null char.

Either reformulate for EAX to start at zero and read the byte at address [a + eax], or subtract the address of a from EAX before printing out the length. Either will work.

EDIT: for the first approach, the main loop would look like this:

```
main:
     nop
     xor eax,eax ; removed the mov eax,a line - eax stays zero
     xor edx,edx
length:
     mov dl, byte[a+eax]         ; eax is the index in the string
     cmp dl,0
     ;The rest stays the same
```

For the second approach, the loop stays the same, but the printing part gets an extra `sub`:

```
print:
     sub eax, offset b ; convert from address to index
     pusha
     push eax
     push msg
     ; The rest is the same
```

This, however, would be the shortest way:

```
main:
    nop
    mov edi, a ; the string we're scanning
    xor al, al ; That's what we're scanning the string for - a null valued byte
    mov ecx, 0ffffffffh ; we bet on string being null terminated - no hard limit on string scanning
    repne scasb ; Once this finishes, ECX is (0xffffffff - length - 1) (because the terminating null is counted too)
    mov eax, 0fffffffeh
    sub eax, ecx    ; Now eax is (0xffffffff - 1 - ecx), which is string length
print:
    ; Same as before
```

Look up the `scas` command and how to use it with `repxx` prefixes. It's almost as if a portion of C RTL (strlen, strcpy and such) is implemented in the Intel CPU instruction set.

On a side note, the snippet has two completely extraneous lines - `xor eax, eax` and `xor edx, edx` in the function's beginning. Both zero out a register that will be overwritten in the next line anyway.

Comment: Thanx for your kind reply. I have already solved it using counter register ecx. Yet, I want to know how can I solve it using eax, Sorry mentor, still I didnot get how to solve it using eax.

Comment: Actually, the fastest way would be `rep scasb` with al=0. Lets you avoid the loop altogether.

Comment: Fantastic anaysis.A students needs nothing more than this.Fantastic, my mentor

Comment: Can you pls advice me how to print only the data in DL?

Comment: Please ask a separate question. I don't understand what do you want.